# Can't find ISCSI drives after NAS firmware update

Tags: debian, network-attached-storage, iscsi, debian-lenny

This is what it's all about: I've got a Linux network with an actual hardware server running two separate virtual machines and a QNAP NAS T-459 Pro+ as a fileserver. Since updating the QNAP firmware on the NAS, the main server cannot access the ISCSI drives anymore.

Effect: All net drives at the workstations are not accessible anymore, so you can't access any file from there.

The hardware server is running XenServer as a virtualisation software, providing one VM as a VPN gateway and another VM as a Samba server (192.168.1.33).

Whenever I try mounting the ISCSI drives on the Samba server using the UUID (as in /etc/fstab), I get:

> server01:/home# mount 2d3e150d-a259-4a82-bfe5-f60c6785bc06 /mnt/nfs/backup -t ext3
>   mount: special device 2d3e150d-a259-4a82-bfe5-f60c6785bc06 does not exist

Though it is possible to access the QNAP-NAS (192.168.1.34) from the Samba server via ssh. I've mounted a NAS-folder on the Samba server using NFS.

Attached I will send you the last entries in /etc/logs/kmsg.

Have you got any ideas? I'm quite desperate, the only thing I could think of is switching the whole ISCSI connections to NFS, though I don't know if that brings any other trouble. What do you think? And could you help me switching it (or solving the problem in another way), as my knowledge end when it comes to NFS and ISCSI? That'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if uuid hasn't changed:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Or:

```
blkid /dev/sda1
```

Maybe fstab entries are outdated by some way?

Comment: Hi Marek, 
thanks for your answer! 


`ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`

returns

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 19. Apr 13:15 7a640380-d986-430d-aaa3-b4fcc89f9035 -> ../../hdb1`


While 

`blkid /dev/sda1`

says:

`/dev/sda1: UUID="1fef18d0-e202-4df3-ace8-59e74b0ae3a6" TYPE="ext3" SEC_TYPE="ext2"`

Though when I try mounting it, the error message is:


server01:/home#mount 2d3e150d-a259-4a82-bfe5-f60c6785bc06
/mnt/nfs/backup -t ext3
mount: special device 2d3e150d-a259-4a82-bfe5-f60c6785bc06 does not exist


What's going on there?

Comment: Why you are trying to mount using uuid, first try mounting by short name (eg. sda1 (mount /dev/sda1 /target)

Comment: Oh, I just took what was written in /etc/fstab

Comment: `server01:/mnt/iscsi_d# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/iscsi_d -t ext3`
`mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist`

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** 
The iscsi-nodes weren't set to login automatically. The directories they were mounted to were locked though and couldn't been used to mount other drives there.

How to fix it:
Find the nodes your iscsi server provides using open-iscsi (need to be installed):

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -tst -p [ISCSI-SERVER IP] -d3
```

Then register them for automatic login:

```
iscsiadm -m node -T [NODE_NAME] -p [ISCSI-SERVER IP] --o update -n node.conn[0].startup -v automatic
```

Restart the iscsi service:

```
/etc/init.d/open-iscsi restart
```

Use  `fdisk -l`  to check if it worked. Should say something like:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 323.3 GB, 323384981504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 39315 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
```

Welcome back your once lost iscsi drive. :)